# The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Int32' and 'System.String' in Action filter Asp.net core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, action-filter, custom-action-filter

I'm working on an `Asp.net core 5` project.
I created an `action filter` that would apply with `HttPost` actions especially with `create`, this filter will check if an object already exist in the database with the same values submitted from the `model`.

**How I use it:**
The filter should receive the `entity` to check in, and the *properties names* to be checked in the `entity` and an *error message* to be displayed in case of a record existing.

**Filter definition:**
It is a bit complex I think

```
public class RecordShouldNotExistFilterAttribute:TypeFilterAttribute
{

    public RecordShouldNotExistFilterAttribute( Type entityType, string errorMessage= "Existe déjà", params string[] propertiesToBeChecked) : base( typeof(RecordShouldNotExistFilter<>).MakeGenericType(entityType))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] {errorMessage , propertiesToBeChecked};
    }

}

public class RecordShouldNotExistFilter<TEntity>:IActionFilter where  TEntity : class
{

    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;
    public           string[]     PropertiesToBeChecked { get; set; }
    public           string       ErrorMessage          { get; set; }

    public RecordShouldNotExistFilter( AppDbContext dbContext ,string errorMessage,params string[] propertiesToBeChecked)
    {
        _dbContext            = dbContext;
        PropertiesToBeChecked = propertiesToBeChecked;
        ErrorMessage          = errorMessage;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext context )
    {

        Expression queryExpression = null;

        context.ActionArguments.TryGetValue( "model" , out var model );

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));

        foreach ( var property in PropertiesToBeChecked )
        {
            var propValue = model?.GetType().GetProperty( property )?.GetValue( model );

            var equalExpression = Expression.Equal( left : Expression.Property( param , property) , right : Expression.Constant( propValue ) );

            queryExpression = queryExpression == null ? equalExpression : Expression.And( queryExpression , equalExpression );
        }

        var condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity , bool>>( queryExpression , param );

        var result = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where( condition );

        if ( result.Any() )
        {
            context.Result = RedirectToActionResult( action : "ExistError" , controller : "/Exception" ,errorModel: new ErrorModel()
                                                                                                         {
                                                                                                             Title       = "Existe déjà" ,
                                                                                                             Description = $"{ErrorMessage}" ,
                                                                                                             ReturnUrl   = "/Dashboard"
                                                                                                         } );
        }


    }

    public void OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext   context )
    {
        
    }

    #region Private methods

    private static RedirectToActionResult RedirectToActionResult(string action, string controller, ErrorModel errorModel)
    {
        return new RedirectToActionResult(action, controller, errorModel);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

**Example of use with actions:**

```
[RecordShouldNotExistFilter(entityType: typeof(PedagogicalSequence), errorMessage: "A record with the same ID already exists",propertiesToBeChecked: nameof(Branche.Id))]
    public IActionResult Create(Branche model)
    {
    //Some logic here
    }
```

**The problem:**

> The problem is in an `Action` I got this error
> InvalidOperationException: The binary operator Equal is not defined
> for the types 'System.Int32' and 'System.String'.
> System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetEqualityComparisonOperator(ExpressionType
> binaryType, string opName, Expression left, Expression right, bool
> liftToNull)

**Error screen:**
[image]

please any help to fix this issue ?

Comment: Are the arguments to Equal the same type?

Comment: Yes, the `Id`'s value sent from submitted in `model` is `string` and his type already `string`

Comment: And the property being checked, of the entity representing the DB items, also a string? (PedagogicalSequence.Id is a string?)

Comment: oh damn, my god you right I send a `typeof()` for wrong entity 
thank you brother

Comment: Can't beat a good bit of cardboard analysis! You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case here:

```
[RecordShouldNotExistFilter(entityType: typeof(PedagogicalSequence), errorMessage: "A record with the same ID already exists",propertiesToBeChecked: nameof(Branche.Id))]
```

I sent a wrong entity.

I changed it and everything's good